# Set a YouTube video's privacy using GData Obj-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, gdata

I know I can set a video as '**Private**', while uploading it to Youtube, by :

```
GDataYouTubeMediaGroup *mediaGroup = [GDataYouTubeMediaGroup mediaGroup];
[mediaGroup setIsPrivate:YES];
```

Is there a similar way to set a video as '**Unlisted**', while uploading it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I wasn't using an updated version of the GData APIs, first I had to make the changes listed here :

[ http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/detail?r=669 ]

Then I used the following code to set the video as 'Unlisted', while uploading it to Youtube :

```
GDataEntryYouTubeUpload *entry;
entry = [GDataEntryYouTubeUpload uploadEntryWithMediaGroup:mediaGroup
                                                      data:data
                                                      MIMEType:mimeType
                                                      slug:filename];

[entry addAccessControl:[GDataYouTubeAccessControl
                        accessControlWithAction:@"list" permission:@"denied"]];
```

Make sure the video is **NOT** set as 'Private' for this to work :

```
[mediaGroup setIsPrivate:NO];
```

Got some major help from :

[ http://groups.google.com/group/gdata-objectivec-client/browse_thread/thread/da69a5ecbb6dfa42?fwc=1 ]